# Reveal UIViewController, vanilla mode

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, cocoa-touch

I want to display a **UIViewController** this way, that is: an *upper* viewcontroller slides out with a left-to-right animation and the *lower* one displays. Then, when you click the left button, this viewcontroller covers the other one again.

[image]

This is a very common UX pattern and I see lots of people doing it with third party components (eg. SWRevealViewController).

The question is: if I *don't* want to do it with a third party library, how can I do it?

Comment: Don't waste your time, there are projects with very detailed features like https://github.com/sascha/DrawerController, I think is the best of all.

Comment: You never waste time when you build things yourself   :-)

Answer (score 0):

*IMO*: Apple has stated that it's more of a design anti-pattern and appeal to popularity shouldn't be considered a good argument for this kind of design.

What you're looking for is a `UIViewController` containment and transitioning. Create a `UIViewController` class that accepts a, say, `menuViewController` (the *lower one* in your case) and an array of view controllers that can be displayed by tapping menu items.

Grab all the titles from the collection of view controllers and display them in menu view controller. Next by tapping the items in menu just use

```
- transitionFromViewController:toViewController:duration:options:animations:completion:
```

method for animating the transition between chosen view controllers.

Comment: Show him this: https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2014/211/ and try debating without "everybody is doing this" argument because, well, it's not an argument.

Comment: It's exactly his argument for about anything  :-(

Answer (score 0):

It not so trivial to make, that's why people suggest to use some 3rd-party library.

But basically you want to create container view controller, add there your menu and main view controller above it and handle gesture recognition.